# Adding matrices based on row and column designation

Tags: r, matrix

I am sure the answer to this is up somewhere, but I don't think I've been using the right search terms.

Here is my issue.  I have multiple matrices (I will simplify to just two here), where each row is a uniquely labeled individual (some of which are shared between matrices, and some of which are not), and common column headings that are shared.

For example:

```
first<-matrix(rbinom(20,1,.5),4,5)
first[,1]=c(122,145,186,199)
colnames(first)<-c("ID",901,902,903,904)
first
      ID 901 902 903 904
[1,] 122   1   0   0   0
[2,] 145   0   0   0   1
[3,] 186   0   0   1   1
[4,] 199   1   0   0   0

second<-matrix(rbinom(30,1,.5),6,5)
second[,1]=c(122,133,142,151,186,199)
colnames(second)<-c("ID",901,902,903,904)
second
      ID 901 902 903 904
[1,] 122   0   1   1   1
[2,] 133   0   0   0   1
[3,] 142   1   1   0   1
[4,] 151   0   1   0   0
[5,] 186   1   0   1   1
[6,] 199   1   0   0   0
```

I would like to add 'first' and 'second' together based upon the 'ID' and column names.  This should result in a matrix with 7 rows (since there are 4 IDs in the 'first' matrix, and 3 new and 3 old IDs in the 'second' matrix: "122,133,142,145,151,186,199"), and the same number of columns.

In this example, the result I would want would be:

```
      ID 901 902 903 904
[1,] 122   1   1   1   1
[2,] 133   0   0   0   1
[3,] 142   1   1   0   1
[4,] 145   0   0   0   1
[5,] 151   0   1   0   0
[6,] 186   1   0   2   2
[7,] 199   2   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a solution without a "for" loop using builtin functions without  success.
So here is my approach

```
set.seed(1) # make it reproducible
first <- matrix(rbinom(20,1,.5),4,5)
first[ ,1] <- c(122, 145, 186, 199)
colnames(first) <- c("ID", 901, 902, 903, 904)

second <- matrix(rbinom(30, 1, .5), 6, 5)
second[ ,1] <- c(122, 133, 142, 151, 186, 199)
colnames(second) <- c("ID", 901, 902, 903, 904)

first

      ID 901 902 903 904
[1,] 122   0   1   1   1
[2,] 145   1   0   0   1
[3,] 186   1   0   1   0
[4,] 199   1   0   0   1

second
      ID 901 902 903 904
[1,] 122   0   0   1   1
[2,] 133   0   0   0   1
[3,] 142   1   1   1   0
[4,] 151   0   1   1   0
[5,] 186   0   1   1   1
[6,] 199   1   0   1   1

## stack them rowise
mat <- rbind(first, second)

ind <- unique(mat[,"ID"])

result <- matrix(nrow = length(ind), ncol = 5)
result[,1] <- ind

for (i in seq_along(ind)) {
    result[i,-1] <- colSums(mat[mat[ ,"ID"] == ind[i], -1, drop = FALSE])
}
colnames(result) <- colnames(mat)

result
      ID 901 902 903 904
[1,] 122   0   1   2   2
[2,] 145   1   0   0   1
[3,] 186   1   1   2   1
[4,] 199   2   0   1   2
[5,] 133   0   0   0   1
[6,] 142   1   1   1   0
[7,] 151   0   1   1   0
```

Answer (score 2):

## Original answer

Building on the approach from @RYogi where you use rownames and colnames to describe your matrix, I propose the following:

```
res <- rbind(first,second)
res <- tapply(res, expand.grid(dimnames(res)), sum)
```

All rows which have equal rownames will be summed.

## When using data frames

If your input is a `data.frame`, the above will not work, as a `data.frame` must not have any duplicate row names. Another approach wich works there as well this:

```
rowsum(rbind(first, second), c(rownames(first), rownames(second)))
```

This approach will work on matrices as well. As it only takes one line, you might consider it simpler. I guess it might be more efficient as well, as it is less general than `tapply`. You could adjust this solution to the data format from your question, where the identifiers are in a separate column:

```
rowsum(rbind(first, second)[,-1], c(first[,1], second[,1]))
```

Note that the result would still have named rows, not a column containing those names.

Funny thing is, I accidentially read about `rowsum` while looking for `rowSums` in a rather complicated approach for the `data.frame` version of this problem here. Lucky me.

## Additional hints

If you find the resulting names `Var1` and `Var2` for the dimensions confusing, you can remove them using

```
names(dimnames(res)) <- NULL
```

If your data really is in the format you describe, with the row names in the first data column, you can change them to proper row names using these commands:

```
rownames(first) <- first[,1]
first <- first[,-1]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but when I used rbind on my real data set (where I used ID as the rownames), the duplicate rownames had a number appended at the end of them.  For example, if ID# 165320128 showed up 3 times, one row would be '165320128', the next '1653201281', and the last '1653201282'

Comment: @user1399311, could it be your original data is stored in data frames instead of matrices? It appears that they exhibit the behaviour you describe, as duplicate row names aren't allowed for a data.frame. You could convert them matrices, but I'll edit my answer to provide a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I set up your problem slightly differently:

```
first <- matrix(rbinom(16,1,.5),4,4)
rownames(first) <- c(122,145,186,199)
colnames(first) <- c(901,902,903,904)

second <- matrix(rbinom(24,1,.5),6,4)
rownames(second) <- c(122,133,142,151,186,199)
colnames(second) <- c(901,902,903,904)
```

The matrices now have named rownames

```
> first
    901 902 903 904
122   1   0   0   1
145   1   0   0   0
186   0   0   1   1
199   1   0   1   1
> second
    901 902 903 904
122   1   1   0   0
133   0   0   1   1
142   1   0   1   0
151   1   0   1   1
186   0   1   0   1
199   0   0   0   0
```

Now it is easy to do set operations on the row names:

```
SumOnID <- function(A, B){
  rnA <- rownames(A)
  rnB <- rownames(B)

  ls.id <- list(ids = intersect(rnA, rnB), #shared indices
                idA = setdiff(rnA, rnB),   #only in A
                idB = setdiff(rnB, rnA))   #only in B

  do.call(rbind, 
    lapply(names(ls.id), function(x){
      if (x == "ids") return(A[x,, drop = F] + B[x,, drop = F])
      if (x == "idA") return(A[x,, drop = F])
      if (x == "idB") return(B[x,, drop = F])
    }))
}
```

Lets try it:

```
> SumOnID(first, second)
    901 902 903 904
122   2   1   1   1
186   1   1   0   1
199   2   1   1   0
145   1   1   0   1
133   1   0   1   1
142   1   0   1   0
151   1   1   1   1
```